# Synaptic / Neataptic simple NEAT XOR solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, neural-network

**EDIT:** I managed to get together couple of simple examples https://github.com/developer239/neural-network-playground

Could anyone help me with simple neat example teaching the net how to solve XOR or some other similar problem? But using the NEAT technique so that I would not have to specify training data set?

Using javascript: https://github.com/cazala/synaptic or https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic

`1. Initialize network
2. Generate generation
3. Go through each genome in generation and evaluate its fitness (how good it is)
4. Take 2 best genomes from generation
5. Merge genomes 50 / 50 at random
6. Mutate final genome
7. Generate second generation`

This would be extremely helpful. Same teqnique is being used here:

https://github.com/ivanseidel/IAMDinosaur

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7XHzqZjXQs

I went through the source code but there is WAY to much stuff going on. I understand the general idea. However I have no idea how to implement the solution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write my own solution. You can find it here: https://github.com/developer239/neural-network-playground/tree/master/neatXOR

The main difference from the solution in documentation is that in `genetic.js` you can dynamically change the learning process.

This is entry file:

```
const genetic = require('./genetic')


genetic.generateRandomPopulation()

for (let iteration = 0; iteration < 1000; iteration += 1) {
  genetic.live()
  genetic.evolve()
}

const genom = genetic.neat.population[0]

console.log(`
  Result for genom with index 0 in the newest population. Note that selection / mutation happened
  after we called last evolve function so this is not necessarily the best genome in the population.

  [0, 0] = ${genom.activate([0, 0])} (should be 0) 
  [1, 1] = ${genom.activate([1, 1])} (should be 0) 
  [0, 1] = ${genom.activate([0, 1])} (should be 1) 
  [1, 0] = ${genom.activate([1, 0])} (should be 1) 
`)
```

This is `genetic.js` file:

```
const { Neat, architect } = require('neataptic')


module.exports = {
  neat: null, // https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/docs/neat/
  possibleInputs: [
    [0, 0], // expected output 0
    [1, 1], // expected output 0
    [0, 1], // expected output 1
    [1, 0], // expected output 1
  ],
  generateRandomPopulation: function () {
    this.neat = new Neat(
      2, // number of inputs
      1, // number of outputs
      null, // fitnessFunction - in this example we are calculating fitness inside live method
      {
        elitism: 5, // this sets how many genomes in population will be passed into next generation without mutation https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_meant_by_the_term_Elitism_in_the_Genetic_Algorithm
        mutationRate: 0.3, // sets the mutation rate. If set to 0.3, 30% of the new population will be mutated. Default is 0.3
        network: // https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/docs/architecture/network/
          new architect.Random(
            2,
            3,
            1,
          ),
      },
    )
  },
  // the closer the output gets to expectedOutput the better
  // note that optimal fitness in this example is 0 neural network seems to work fine though
  calculateFitness: function (expectedOutput, output) {
    let closeCount = Math.abs(expectedOutput - output)
    let fitness = closeCount * -1
    return fitness
  },
  live: function () {
    // increment generation index
    this.neat.generation += 1

    // loop through each genome
    for (let genomeIndex in this.neat.population) {
      const possibleInputs = this.possibleInputs
      const genome = this.neat.population[genomeIndex]
      genome.score = 0

      // loop through each input
      for (let i = 0; i < possibleInputs.length; i += 1) {
        let input = possibleInputs[i]
        // test each input
        let output = genome.activate(input)[0]

        // calculate fitness for each output
        // we have 4 different inputs so the total score is sum of 4 different fitness values
        if (i <= 1) {
          genome.score += this.calculateFitness(0, output)
        } else {
          genome.score += this.calculateFitness(1, output)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  evolve: function () {
    const neat = this.neat
    console.log(`[generation ${neat.generation}] Average score: ${neat.getAverage()} (the closer to zero the better)`)

    // sort by genome.score in descending order
    neat.sort()

    // our new population will be here
    let newPopulation = []

    // we want to push neat.elitism number of best genomes into the new population automatically
    for (let i = 0; i < neat.elitism; i++) {
      newPopulation.push(neat.population[i])
    }

    // we want to get offspring from the current population and push it into the new population
    for (let i = 0; i < neat.popsize - neat.elitism; i++) {
      newPopulation.push(neat.getOffspring())
    }

    // set new population
    neat.population = newPopulation
    // mutate the population
    neat.mutate()
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example on Neataptic's [README.md](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic).

```
// this network learns the XOR gate (through neuro-evolution)
var network = new Network(2,1);

var trainingSet = [
  { input: [0,0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0,1], output: [1] },
  { input: [1,0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1,1], output: [0] }
];

await network.evolve(trainingSet, {
  equal: true,
  error: 0.03
 });
```

Neataptic has it all built-in so all you have to provide is a data set. If you need more info on how this has been set up, [read this article](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/neuro-evolution-on-steroids-82bd14ddc2f6).

For problems with dynamic solutions, a custom loop and fitness function has to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old question, and neataptic isn't very widely used, but I found a much simpler way to implement this so i thought i'd share

```
const { Neat } = require('neataptic');

function fitness(network) {
    let score = 0;

    score += Math.abs(0 - network.activate([0,0])[0]);
    score += Math.abs(1 - network.activate([0,1])[0]);
    score += Math.abs(1 - network.activate([1,0])[0]);
    score += Math.abs(0 - network.activate([1,1])[0]);
    score = -score;

    return score;
}

(async () => {
    const neat = new Neat(2 ,1 ,fitness, {});
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        await neat.evolve();
    }
    const fittest = neat.getFittest();

    console.log(fitness(fittest));
    console.log(fittest.activate([0,0]));
    console.log(fittest.activate([0,1]));
    console.log(fittest.activate([1,0]));
    console.log(fittest.activate([1,1]));
})();
```